# TeamCity pull request from bitbucket cloud

Tags: bitbucket, teamcity, bitbucket-cloud

Since bitbucket 2020.1 there is integration for BitBucket Cloud in TeamCity.

In my project I want to achieve situation:

- there is a hotfix / release branch
- in BB I create pull request from that branch to master

I want to have automatic build in TC after creating this PR.
I tried this build feature (pull request) but after creating PR in BB nothing happens in TC.

I found this [instruction](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html#Bitbucket+Cloud+Pull+Requests)  but it still doesn't want to cooperate.

Comment: i feel your pain bro, same for me. i see pending build with PR in TC but trigger wont work. 
Since Bitbucket Cloud does not create dedicated branches for pull requests, this build feature monitors directly source branches in a source repository (forks are not supported).
+ This option will not work if the VCS root uses an SSH fetch URL or employs anonymous authentication.

Comment: From the instruction: `build configuration must have a VCS trigger enabled` - do you have one?

Comment: Any luck with this? I've tried the suggestions in this SO Q&A as well as guidance from both bitbucket and teamcity, but teamcity simply does not see that a pull request was created. I suspect there's a nuance that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you've posted, it seems you've setup TeamCity to know about BitBucket.
However you need to also let BitBucket trigger TeamCity https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Configuring+VCS+Post-Commit+Hooks+for+TeamCity?_ga=2.130253711.1405663514.1613160148-1185856109.1612616927